# Server performance issue while running cakephp web application

Tags: php, nginx, cakephp, amazon-ec2, web-applications

Our application server is getting down or slow randomly throughout the day, CakePHP 2 application with Mysql is running on this server. We have some cronjobs set up and all are working perfectly.

This performance issue mostly occurs at business time (Day time)

Server configuration: **AWS instance t2.large**, **FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p11**, Disk space 20% free (30GB)

I go through many server logs as well as application logs like below

Nginx error log (Few lines from the log)

```
2020/04/30 23:04:57 [info] 66440#101049: *71645 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2020/04/30 23:05:01 [info] 66440#101049: *71820 kevent() reported that client XX.XX.XX.XX closed keepalive connection
2020/04/30 23:05:42 [info] 66440#101049: *72494 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

dmesg.today Log (Few lines)

```
sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff800a70cf7a8: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (62 occurrences)
sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff800a70cf7a8: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (57 occurrences)
sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff80115d9e7a8: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (63 occurrences)
sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff80115d9e7a8: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (126 occurrences)
```

HTOP outcome

```
PHP-fpm: pool www, sometimes consumes 100% of CPU and memory
```

NodePing Alert (Receiving continuous notification in day time)

```
 failed the HTTP check. It is down as of Thu Apr 30 2020 12:29:09 GMT-0700.Timeout.
 HTTP is back up after being down for 4 minutes as of Thu Apr 30 2020 23:28:19 GMT-0700.
```

Nginx.conf file

```
user  www;
worker_processes  2;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_header_timeout 3000;
    client_body_timeout 3000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    server_name_in_redirect on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_names_hash_max_size 8192;   

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;    
    sendfile        on;    
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";


    include /etc/nginx/ssl/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        autoindex off;
        server_name  localhost;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        root /usr/local/www/html/webroot;
        index index.html index.php;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
           # set $new_uri $uri;
           # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           try_files $uri $uri?$args $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $new_uri;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_pass /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50.html {
           root /etc/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ /(\.ht|\.user.ini|\.git|\.hg|\.bzr|\.svn) {
            deny  all;
        }

    }

    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name  *.XXXX.com;
        ssl     on;
        ssl_certificate      /XXXXX.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /XXXXX.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping 

        root /usr/local/www/html/webroot;
        index index.html index.php;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
           # set $new_uri $uri;
           # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           try_files $uri $uri?$args $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off;}
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off;}
        location ~ /.well-known { allow all; }

    }

    ##
    # Cache Proxy
    ##
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=24h max_size=512m;  
    proxy_temp_path /var/tmp;  

}
```

below are Some CPU utilization screens from AWS console

[image: 2 weeks]
[image: 1 week]
[image: 3 days]

Above are some of my findings to found the issue, but I don't know what is causing poor server performance. Please suggest

**UPDATE**

I observe that in business hours (TTFB) is taking too much time (20 -25 sec)
I check the log of Mysql queries running on that page took Total Time: 1441 ms
So, Something else taking up time to load the page.

HTOP outcome at that time
[image]

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. Any swap space?

Comment: In reviewing your HTOP page in top right reports, Tasks: 66, 0 thr; 2 running - Not sure I have ever seen 0 thr on a system that is functioning.  If you still need assistance, please consider posting Additional information requested on May 1.  I know it takes time to gather this information.

Comment: @WilsonHauck The main issue is the TTFB delay, which occurs when the site has some traffic. I think Mysql queries running using CakePHP is the culprit here. So I am working on the query optimization.

Comment: JetProfile.com could assist, a free trial with no expiration date is available, set Polling Interval to 10 seconds.  Top Queries should be your primary focus.